# c++ Float Output

Tags: c++

I had a question on an assignment:

"then after you've received the inputs from the user, do the math for final percentage, and cast the result as a float using `static_cast<float>`, `(float)`, or `1.0*`"

So I have this for my calculations:

```
totalUserPoints = usersHomeworkScore + usersExamScore + usersReciationScore ;
scorePercentage = (totalUserPoints/totalPossiblePoints);
```

Then the output is:

```
cout << endl << "Your total points for class is: " << totalUserPoints << endl ;
cout<< "Which is a precentage of:  " << scorePercentage <<" %" <<endl;
```

However I have been told I still have not met the requirement. Should I do this to meet the requirement:

```
//Calculations for total points recieved and classroom percentage.
totalUserPoints = usersHomeworkScore + usersExamScore + usersReciationScore ;
scorePercentage = static_cast<float>(totalUserPoints)/(totalPossiblePoints);


//Outputs the total class points and if they would recieve an A
cout << endl << "Your total points for class is: " << totalUserPoints << endl ;
cout << "Which is a precentage of:  " << (scorePercentage*100) <<" %" <<endl;
```

Or am I still miss understanding? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with what you wrote initially. The second bit is just pointless nonsense you can include to satisfy your instructor. Consider casting any int to a float manually, like `(float)totalPossiblePoints` just to be safe, marks-wise.

Comment: Kinda what I was thinking cause you could easily just do it how I originally wrote it and save a whole bunch of code but he was saying I was missing it. So the second part is probably what he is looking for with the "static_cast <int>((scorePercentage) * 100 )"

Comment: What are the types of `totalUserPoints`, `totalPossiblePoints`, and `scorePercentage`? (Also, note that you don't need parentheses in `scorePercentage = totalUserPoints/totalPossiblePoints;`).

Answer (score 0):

`scorePercentage = (totalUserPoints/totalPossiblePoints);` is wrong considering that percentage has to be outcome after multiplication with 100.

Instead you can do:

```
scorePercentage = (totalUserPoints/totalPossiblePoints)*100
```

Note that, you don't need any casting or multiplication by 1.0 here because this is an double divided by an int operation, *the compiler handles this by converting the int into a double.*

Furthermore, casting shouldn't be needed while printing that value, instead you could have the exact result at the first time you do the calculation.

So, replace

```
cout << "Which is a precentage of:  " <<static_cast <int>((scorePercentage) * 100 ) <<" %" <<endl;
```

with

```
cout << "Which is a precentage of:  "  << scorePercentage << " %" <<endl;
```

Comment: I think OP declaring totalUserPoints as double was a mistake. It should be int for the lesson.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is clearly homework. Why go to SO for it?

First, percentage is *100. Then totalUserPoints should still be int. The thing the exercise wants to teach is (float)((totalUserPoints*100)/totalPossiblePoints) vs. ((float)totalUserPoints*100.0f)/(float)totalPossiblePoints. How is doing the division in float vs. int different? Why?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare scorePercentage and totalPossiblePoints as double, so you do not have any problems.

But if you can not make that statement, you should do the following casting:

```
scorePercentage = static_cast<float>( totalUserPoints/static_cast<double>(totalPossiblePoints) );
```

or also has this alternative (but with the risk that it could cause data loss when casting in totalUserPoints):

```
scorePercentage = static_cast<float>(totalUserPoints)/static_cast<float>(totalPossiblePoints);
```

If you also want to output a rounded output to zero decimal places, use [setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/):

```
cout << setprecision(0) << endl << "Your total points for class is: " << totalUserPoints << endl ;
cout << setprecision(0) << "Which is a precentage of:  " << (scorePercentage*100) <<" %" <<endl;
```